# Create a non spatial index on an attribute in QGIS before joining two layers

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, attribute-index

I’m trying to join a .dbf which contains no spatial data to a shapefile containing spatial data. Ideally I’d like to create an attribute index on the join field in the .dbf before I join it to the shapefile.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Also in the join menu there are two tick box options:

1. Cache join layer in virtual memory
2. Create attribute index on join field

Can anybody tell me what these two options mean? Is the attribute index created during the join if I was to tick this or is it done before the join?

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: I won't answer to your question but suggest to do it in a different way. Use the Spatialite-gui program and import both the shapefile and extra attributes from the DBF file into Spatialite db. Create indexes on the joining fields with Spatialite-gui and make a spatial view with the Query/View Composer tool. Once this is done you can open the view with QGIS as "Add SpatiaLite Layer" and joins and indexes will work fine for you.